# Are My Temps To High?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, desktop-computer, temperature

Speedfan throws up the fire symbol and red exclamation beside my GPU temp and I want to check that this is not a huge concern for me.  System details

> Tower: Corsair Carbide Series SPEC-03
>   MoBo: ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0 AM3+
>   Chip: AMD FX8350
>   RAM: 8 GB
>   Video Card: EVGA GeForce GT 610

Tower sits on the ground with plenty of room for air-flow on either side, as well as the front/back.  Here are my temps
GPU temp 50C when not in use jumps to 60 (or over) when in use
Temp1 32C
Temp2 26C
Temp3 -128C
HD1 24C
HD0 25C
Core 11C

Should I be concerned about the GPU being 50C and higher?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this question is pretty off topic for a site like Super User, since it has no canonical answer - different GPU's will want different temperatures, and there are MANY factors involved here. I would suggest searching the limitations on what your GPU should be reaching, and work from there.

Comment: Go to Configure > Temperatures > Select a temperature. Here you can change the "Warning" temperatures and customise them for your hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not for this card at all. Thermal shutdown for a GT 610 occurs at around 102~c so you are well under. There are plenty of posts online about overclocking this card successfully. I wouldn't worry about it until you reach 80~c+ and at that time I'd just look into finding a better way to cool your internals or getting a better card.

As far as speedfan showing flames: Apps like this will only show you what they know... If the data the app pulls from doesn't know the thermal shutdown of the card you're using then it is either guessing or giving you a generic answer. They should show a "???" instead of a flame.

50-75~c is pretty reasonable for video cards at full throttle. GPUs typically run much hotter than other chips such as CPUs.

Comment: 75 degrees Celcius is normal for me with dust. I would get worried if it exceeds 90 degrees...

Answer (score 1):

SpeedFan's fire symbol doesn't really mean anything by default; you must configure the thresholds for each status symbol yourself.

60 degrees seems like a rather realistic temperature while the card is in heavy use. You might want to check your GPU fan to be sure it is cooling well: if it is very high (75-100%), you may want to check for dust blocking the ventilation within the card. If it is still quite low at these temperatures, your card is working correctly.

You should be concerned when the card is higher than roughly 85-90 degrees Celsius, as running in this temperature for prolonged periods of time may cause damage. Most cards shut down automatically at about 100-110 degrees Celsius to prevent extensive damage.